# Neo4j WHERE NOT clause for different nodes not working

Tags: neo4j, cypher, where-clause

I will explain briefly my query:

```
match (a)-[:requires]-(b), 
      (a)-[:instanceOf]->(n)<-[:superclassOf*]-(c:Host_configuration),
      (h)-[:instanceOf]->(z)<-[:superclassOf*]-(t:Host)  
where not b = h 
return distinct a, b
```

My wish is to return all `(a)-[:requires]-(b)` patterns (where `a` is somehow a subclass of `Host_configuration` but `b` is not a subclass of `Host`. 
This query however returns **also** nodes that actually are subclasses of `Host`

**EDIT**
I don't want to retrieve all `a` elements connected to `b` elements that are not tied to `Host`. I want to retrieve all patterns between `a` and `b` that are not like `(a)-[:requires]-(h)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
match (a)-[:requires]-(b), 
      (a)-[:instanceOf]->(n)<-[:superclassOf*]-(:Host_configuration)
where not (b)-[:instanceOf]->(z)<-[:superclassOf*]-(:Host)  
return distinct a, b
```

It's possible to directly update the where clause with the path you want to exclude. You can define the where clause to exclude `b` where it is a subclass of `Host`.

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe you should care about the *direction* of the `(a)-[:requires]-(b)` pattern. If you do not specify a direction, you would not know who requires whom AND you might also get the same node pair *twice* (in opposite orders). In my answer, I assume you meant `(a)-[:requires]->(b)`, but you can easily reverse the direction if need be.
2. For efficiency, you should perform *both* `instanceOf/superclassOf` tests [using path patterns in a WHERE clause](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#query-where-patterns). Such a path pattern just checks for a *single match* before succeeding, and does not bother to expend the resources to hunt down *all possible matches*. (By the way, a path pattern in a WHERE clause cannot introduce new variables.)
3. Once the above issues are taken care of, your `MATCH` clause would just be `MATCH (a)-[:requires]->(b)`, and any given `a/b` pair would only be found once (as long as your DB has at most one `requires` relationship going *from* a given node *to* another given node). So that should mean that your `RETURN` clause can omit the `DISTINCT` option, which would be more efficient.

So, this may work better for you:

```
MATCH (a)-[:requires]->(b)
WHERE
  (a)-[:instanceOf]->()<-[:superclassOf*]-(:Host_configuration) AND
  NOT (b)-[:instanceOf]->()<-[:superclassOf*]-(:Host)
RETURN a, b
```

By the way, it would also be more efficient for the `MATCH` clause to specify the node labels for `a` and `b`, so that the DB does not have to scan *every node* in the DB. I have not done that in my answer.